# How to detect swipe direction in Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I know how to detect swiping in libgdx but I am having a problem when I swipe to a certain direction, btw I use GestureListener.

```
        if(velocityX > 0) {
            System.out.println("right");        
        }else if(velocityY > 0 && velocityX > 0){
            System.out.println("down");
        }else if(velocityY < 0){
            System.out.println("up");
        }
```

Basically what happens is when I swipe upwards or downwards it sometimes printout "right". What I want to happen is to detect in which direction the pointer going to, because if you use velocityX and velocityY then you swipe diagonally it will detect two directions which is up and right or down and right. In my case if the user swipe diagonally it should only be detected as a up or down gesture and it should not include left and right swiping.

**Update:**

```
 if(Math.abs(velocityY) > Math.abs(velocityX)){
          if(velocityY > 0)
              System.out.println("down");
          else if(velocityY < 0)
              System.out.println("up");
      }else if(Math.abs(velocityX) > Math.abs(velocityY))
          if(velocityX > 0)
              System.out.println("right");
```

it basically print out the direction that is greater than the other direction

Comment: You need to check `velocityY` in the first condition. BTW, as things stand, the `&& velocityX > 0` is always false in the `else if` - it would have been matched by the first condition if it were true.

Comment: @Andy Turner - what is .abs() method? cause I tried it and it gives me the same value, for example: velocityY and Math.abs(velocityY) have the same value.

Comment: [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs(double)): it returns the absolute value (x if x >= 0; -x if x < 0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing you can do is to decide if the motion is "more left-right" or "more up-down":

```
if (Math.abs(velocityX) > Math.abs(velocityY)) {
  // More left-right.
} else {
  // More up-down.
}
```

Then, you pick which of the "more" directions it is, eg in the "more left-right" block in the conditional:

```
if (velocityX >= 0) {
  System.out.println("Right");
} else {
  System.out.println("Left");
}
```

Similarly for `velocityY`.

Note that this basically divides the direction space into 4 quadrants, divided at the lines `vy = vx` and `vy = -vx`.

[image]